# 15 minutes elapsed time from datetime.now

Tags: linux, datetime, linux-kernel

I am receiving satellite data on every 15 minutes interval.
I am calling the script at 
date -d "-15 min"
*/15 * * * * myscript.sh
But, some times, the satellite may is delayed 3-10 minutes.
in such cases, I(myscript.sh) am not able to catch the file.

#

So, any solution to pick the multiple of last 15 minutes using date option or any ?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Erm, could it be that the job itself is taking 3-10 minutes to run?  Cron will spawn a job each minute, but if the system is overloaded, it's just taking a long time?  Incidentally, if you have a task you want to run every minute, cron is rarely the right tool for that job.  Consider writing a script or app that trigger a task each minute.

Comment: just now, I edited the question @Stephan

Answer (score 0):

if you need to run your script every 15min

You can get the current unix timestamp with date "+%s", find the current quarter-hour with some simple math (my example is in bash) and print it back with a better format with date :

```
curdate=`date "+%s"`
curquarter=$(($curdate - ($curdate % (15 * 60))))
date -d"@$curquarter"
```

The @ syntax to set the current date and time from a timestamp is a GNU extention to date, if it don't works on your OS, you can do the same like this (don't forget to specify UTC, otherwise, it won't work) :

```
date -d"1970-01-01 $curquarter seconds UTC"
```

Comment: curdate=`date  -d "-15 min" "+%s"`;
curquarter=$(($curdate - ($curdate % (15 * 60))));
date -u -d"@$curquarter";
echo "current dateIST:$(date)";
echo "current dateUTC:$(date -u)"

Comment: I did small change based on my requirement. Your answer is very helpful.

Comment: the output of date is needed in %Y%m%d%H%S style. How to do this ?

Comment: if you got the timestamp you can display it as a string 
date -d @"yourtimestamp"
example:
date -d @1267619929